# Unexpected character ('?' (code 65279 / 0xfeff)) json_encode PHP

Tags: php, json, retrofit

I get this error when trying to consume an API call with RETROFIT 2.

Unexpected character ('?' (code 65279 / 0xfeff)).

Basically Retrofit just fails to decode the json response  due to that special character.

I tried to analyse my Json with http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and I noticed this special charactere.

The way I generate the Json is with PHP

```
echo json_encode($this->places,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Is there a way to get rid of that character. Is it comming from my json or from the echo command.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently is that I just needed to encode my .php file with UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: I am having the same problem using Retrofit 2. Is this answer is true?

Comment: I can't understand the UTF-8 without BOM. Can you help me to know how to set into the my php file.

Comment: @vasupujy When you create you php file encode it with UTF-8 without BOM.

Answer (score -2):

You need to parse your content to remove this special char, before encoding to json.